# Why can't I cast an int to a string within this ternary operation

Tags: c#

I left some code out for brevity...

```
int id = Convert.ToInt32(Page.RouteData.Values["id"]);
var q = db.Categories.SingleOrDefault(x => x.categoryID == id);

ddlCategory.SelectedValue = q.parentID == 0 ? 0 : id.ToString();
```

I get the error:

*Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'int' and 'string'* (It's talking about the `id.ToString()` piece.)

I tried `Convert.ToString()` and I tried putting `(string)` infront of `id` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because the two return values of the ternary are not of the same type -- one is `int` and the other is `string`. The compiler cannot deduce what the ternary expression's return type is.

Solution: Return the same type from both branches, or cast one of them to a base of the other. `object` will do fine.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that.

Comment: @Nick: Happens to the best of us.

Answer (score 5):

Because your are trying to make the ternary operator evaluate to either an int (`0`) or a string (`id.ToString()`). Replace the `0` with `"0"`.